# Flutter not building iOS application, is it a swift error?

Tags: swift, xcode, build, flutter, android-studio-3.0

I'm not longer able to build an iOS app with XCode, even a brand new flutter application will not run.

Here's the version of Android Studio:

Android Studio 3.1.4
Build #AI-173.4907809, built on July 23, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b01 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Mac OS X 10.13.6

Here's the version of XCode:

Version 9.4.1 (9F2000)

I get the following error:

Launching lib/main.dart on Andrea's iPad in debug mode...
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: XG2RLBENW5
Starting Xcode build...
Xcode build done.
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    2018-09-15 15:56:05.469 xcodebuild[39750:2818902]  DVTAssertions: Warning in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport-14098/Xcode3Core/LegacyProjects/Frameworks/DevToolsCore/DevToolsCore/BuildSystem/Runtime/PBXTargetBuildContext.mm:757
    Details:  unexpected successful exit code from cancelled command 
    Object:   
    Method:   -createCommandInvocationRecordFromInvocation:
    Thread:   {number = 9, name = (null)}
    Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
    ** BUILD FAILED **

Xcode's output:
↳
    === BUILD TARGET Runner OF PROJECT Runner WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
    The use of Swift 3 @objc inference in Swift 4 mode is deprecated. Please address deprecated @objc inference warnings, test your code with “Use of deprecated Swift 3 @objc inference” logging enabled, and then disable inference by changing the "Swift 3 @objc Inference" build setting to "Default" for the "Runner" target.
    The use of Swift 3 @objc inference in Swift 4 mode is deprecated. Please address deprecated @objc inference warnings, test your code with “Use of deprecated Swift 3 @objc inference” logging enabled, and then disable inference by changing the "Swift 3 @objc Inference" build setting to "Default" for the "Runner" target.
    === BUILD TARGET Runner OF PROJECT Runner WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
    /Users/pbirdsall/Documents/highline/LeverageGoogleServersPlist/GoogleService-Info.plist:0: error: reading data: The file “GoogleService-Info.plist” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file.
Could not build the precompiled application for the device.

Error launching application on Andrea's iPad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is saying:

> "An App ID with Identifier 'com.test.flutterApp' is not available.
>   Please enter a different string"

You need a different bundle id for your project as com.test.flutterApp may be registered under different Apple ID. Change it to anything unique and try to run it

**EDIT**

The new error says: GoogleService-Info.plist couldn't be found at

```
/Users/pbirdsall/Documents/highline/LeverageGoogleServersPlist/GoogleService-Info.plist
```

Make sure you have the plist file.

Comment: I had inadvertently posted the wrong error message initially.

Comment: @PeterBirdsall i have updated my answer. See if it helps :)